# how to find number of duplicate elements in an array in "c"

Tags: arrays, c, duplicates

I've found the below code in a website. this code works but i'm not able to understand it. can anyone please take time and help me understanding it. I'm from mechanical Engineering background, started to learn programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10],i,j,n,c=0 ;
    printf("Enter size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter elements in array :\n ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nelement - %d:",i);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=-1)
        {
            for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(a[i]==a[j])
                {
                    c++;
                    a[j]=-1;
                }
            }
         }      
    }
    printf("duplicate numbers in the  array: %d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any particular part, you have problems understanding with?

Comment: I didn't understood nested loops part.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Enter size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);`   the code only allocates 10 entries in array `a[]`.  What if the user enters 20?

Answer (score 0):

This code is all about looping and indexing. The first user prompt sets the size of the array and saves that to n. The second user prompt sets each index in the array of size n set earlier. Now for the nested for loops. First of all, if an element has a value of -1, it is skipped. In order to check for duplicates, each number must check each element found at an index greater than itself. Thus, element 1 must check element 2, element 3, and so on. Element 2 must check element 3, element 4, and so on. If a match is found, one of the elements is set to -1 (so to not double count later on) and a duplicate counter is incremented. I would recommend tracing an easy example i.e. a[4] = {1, 2, 1, 3}.

Comment: can i know in detail where each element is checking other elements. For example the data given by the user is {1,1,2,2,1}. I was thinking after first iteration the first and second numbers gets compared and the second for loop condition gets satisfied and the second number/element i.e., a[1] will be replaced with the value -1. and after that where will the loop exit. and how is the first number is compared with remaining 3 numbers after the first iteration.

Comment: Well...the very first thing I want to say. This code is not perfect. If there are two numbers (-1)in the array, it will not see a match.

Comment: What's the point of figuring out how bad code works? It is better to write your own code that will work correctly.

Comment: @Генс  That depends on how this snippet was defined to work. If the definition is *count duplicates for positivie numbers*  then the code is ok ...  Nonetheless, I'd probably sort the array first and then count the duplicates in one iteration. Because sorting is O(n logn) and not O(n^2) like this approach ...

Comment: @Генс A real problem of that code is, that `a[10]` is initialized as a fixed sized array of size 10, instead of depending on the entered value of `n`. It's not a big problem if `n <= 10` but it will probably crash if `n` gets greater than 10 ...

Comment: '\0' instead of -1 is quite suitable for the role of a special character. In order to avoid overflowing the array, you can specify n=10 at the beginning; then a[n]; and then enter any value for n

Comment: @Azharuddin Think of the outer loop (variable i) selecting one element to compare against all the others. Then the inner loop (variable j) iterates over the elements greater in index. Let's trace a little:
i = 0
j = 1
Thus, a[0] = a[1] and a[1] is set to -1. Counter is incremented and we move to j = 2. When a no match occurs, j is simply incremented instead i.e. .a[0] != a[2], a[0] != a[3], ... Inner loop terminates and i increments to 2. a[2] = -1 so it's skipped. a[3] then checks against a[4] only. As mentioned above, the code is not robust enough to find all duplicates in all inputs.

Comment: @Azharuddin Don't forget that the outer for loop terminates once the condition i<n is false. So a value being -1 doesn't have an effect on whether the loop exits or not.

Comment: @Генс How is `'\0'`  better than `-1`? If you set `a[i] = '\0'` after you counted it, you won't be able to count the zeros, because `'\0' == 0` in C ...

Comment: @Генс Yeah, one could initialize `n` to a fixed value instead of reading it from the user. But instead of the obvious array overflow error in the code, you decided to criticize on an detail without knowing under what premises this code was written ...

Comment: The overflow problem, as I have already said, is solved without much effort. I have already told you how to do this. n=10; a[n]; printf("%d",n); . But I have not yet found a solution to make this code convenient for the entire range of numbers ,and not just excluding -1 . My suggestion to use '\0' is wrong. Therefore, there is no solution yet.

Comment: @Генс I know how to solve the overflow problem. But that isn't my point. Instead of talking about issues which may not be issues at all (because nobody knows, whether the original problem this code was written for was about the "entire range of numbers" or just postive numbers) you should point out the real problems of the code first ...  So, yes, this is quite bad code. But not for the reasons you mentioned ...

Comment: @Генс But yes, you are right, there cannot be a general solution for counting all values from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` (at least not with this approach), because one always needs one special value, which denotes "there is no value in this cell of the array". And this special value will of course always be `>= INT_MIN` and `<= INT_MAX`

Comment: Thanks for understanding. I tried to find this special character, but I don't know where and how to find it. It would be great to see such a code. This would be useful for many.

Comment: @Генс as I already said: A better approach would be first sorting the array (ascending or descending doesn't matter). Then you can go over the array with a simple for loop like this `for (i = 1; i < n; i++) if (arr[i] == arr[i-1]) c++;` Is faster, more readable, way easier to understand and doesn't rely on any "special values" ...

Comment: The bull's-eye.